# Layers in a swf refuse to load (occasionally, after a cache clear)

Tags: actionscript, flash, actionscript-2, layer

I have a swf with four frames. The first frame loads an external class that acts as traffic controller - looks at the root flashvars being passed in and redirects to frame 2, 3, or 4.

Frame 2 is a basic login screen. There's 5 layers - 2 background layers, the login screen, and a dummy text field. I also have trace statements on every layer, which I have speaking with javascript and writing out to the Firebug console. Since the swf requires database access to know what to do, it only works on a server.

The issue I'm having is that, occasionally, not all the layers on frame 2 load. All the actionscript on every layer fires successfully. What I'll do is clear my cache, and roughly 1 out of every 3 times, the only layer that's loaded is the bottom layer, or the bottom two layers.

I've removed the login movie clip and replaced it with dummy text - nothing. I put a preloader on the first frame - nothing. I created a loader swf to, in turn, load this problematic swf - nothing. I thought it might have something to do with order of rendering so I made those bottom layers semi-transparent - nothing.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to further diagnose this problem? While it's intermittent, it happens often enough to demand a fix.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to leave this outstanding - what I ended up doing was heavily restructuring the swf and the problem ended up fixing itself.

I think the issue was that layers were loading out of order (or something) and so the background layer was sitting on top of everything else. Or breaking everything else. Who knows!

Answer (score 0):

Try combining all visual elements on those layers into one movieclip, and place that movie clip in a layer below the actions.

It happened once with me in a similar case and that was the solution.

Hope it works!